# Webgl Context Lost and not restored

Tags: javascript, memory, webgl

I have a problem with webgl context lost/restored.

My application is very heavy with allot of information, graphs, lists, ... and map.

In the map i'm using webGL in order to get the best performances. My code is handling context lost and restored properly.

I'm starting a big operation that causes loading data from the server, parsing it,... This sometimes making the browser loose my webgl context. The problem is that the context is never restored. When I do again this big operation, then i got the restore event.

In my opinion it is related to memory and the garbage collector freeing time.

But I don't really know what to do, and how to solve this.

Answer (score 5):

An approach to handling the lost could be to recreate the canvas and re-initialize your application for the GL parts. In the end, all resources are gone, so the added overhead for context re-creation should not be too troubling and you can take action immediately when the `webglcontextlost` event arrived.

(not sure if that's the best idea though...)

Commenting on the Answer by Raziza regarding `WEBGL_lose_context`:

Don't use this one like you proposed there. This extension is merely a debugging tool and should only be used to simulate this behavior.

See also here: https://www.khronos.org/registry/webgl/extensions/WEBGL_lose_context/

Answer (score 0):

Found a way to call restore context manually. Don't know if it is good/smart to do, but it is working for me.

We do it by using the extension `WEBGL_lose_context`.
[MDN reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WEBGL_lose_context/restoreContext)

```
// Loading the extension
var ext = gl.getExtension("WEBGL_lose_context"); 

...
// This code in the context lost event, wait 3 secs for forcing 
// restore context
var restoreTimeout = setTimeout(function() { 
     ext.restoreContext(); 
}, 3000);

...
// This code in restore context event
// incase we got restore not from my timeout, i'm canceling it
restoreTimeout && clearTimeout(restoreTimeout);
```

Comment: I had a similar situation in NW.js, calling ``event.preventDefault()`` in the event handler for ``webglcontextlost`` simply did not restore the context as it was supposed to, using ``ext.restoreContext()`` works but only if you set ``ext = gl.getExtension("WEBGL_lose_context");`` BEFORE the context lost event is triggered. (otherwise calling the extension returns ``null``)

Comment: I was wrong! ``.restoreContext()`` only works if the context was lost from using ``.loseContext()`` manually, otherwise (in natural circumstances) it doesn't do anything. It is specifically made for the simulation of loosing the context. **From [the docs](https://www.khronos.org/registry/webgl/extensions/WEBGL_lose_context/):** if the context was not lost via ``loseContext()``, generate an ``INVALID_OPERATION`` error.

Comment: Another way to lose and restore the context is simply add a button to your DOM that creates new canvas and gets the webgl context in a loop.. From what I've checked in chrome - after 15 total contexts the oldest/not used context is lost and once the other context (our main context) need to be display it is restored

Comment: My issue is related to loosing the context NATURALLY, this means that the context is lost (most likely) because a different application is requesting more resources, as WebGL is fluid, it cannot be held in one place, so we get the "context lost" error. Normally, following the instructions from the docs, it should be as easy as doing ``event.preventDefault()`` in the context lost event. BUT IT DOES NOT WORK. ``.restoreContext()`` does absolutely nothing unless you call ``.loseContext()`` manually before it.

Comment: I've even experimented with ``Node.cloneNode()`` in an attempt to clone the canvas to request a new webgl context, this did not work either. It is my strong believe that this is a chrome bug and there is absolutely no way of restoring the context in chrome atm. I've tried everything I can think of for a month, and have not yet found any solution to this. Adding a button to the DOM is unexceptable as we are working on a video player for NW.js/Electron that binds with the VLC binaries and draws the video frames to a canvas, loosing the webgl context stops the video feed.

Comment: Maybe i'm not fully understand you but, When chrome/other browser is loosing the context because of too many resources needed, it is basically loosing all the data. Meaning, buffers are deleted, Shaders, Textures, states, and all the rest of what you have used or created. Fully reset. When the context restores (Whenever the browser wants to draw your context) you will get the event and will have to create/upload all your data to the GPU again, meaning, shaders, textures,.... The button i suggested is just for debugging your the loosing and restore context code